# Caixa mostrando a sintaxe quando digito print()

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ocorre quando estou programando em python, como na imagem:
[image: Imagem exemplo da caixa que estou citando]

Consigo fechar apertando esc, mas apenas momentaneamente, volta quando quando utilizo outro print ou faço o uso de uma vírgula.

Ocorre apenas com o print().

Comment: Adicionar `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` no _setting_ resolve?

Comment: @CmteCardeal Resolveu, muito obrigado! Passei direto por essa config quando tentei resolver.

Comment: esta resposta me foi de ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/569065/como-fa%C3%A7o-pra-tirar-essa-caixa-de-explica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-vs-code