# Como faço pra tirar essa caixa de explicação do vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

É uma caixa de mensagem que descreve a funcionalidade de alguma tag, elemento,etc que você estiver escrevendo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFyrS.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clique na engrenagem no canto inferior esquerdo do VSCode, em seguida clique em
[Configurações](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcok4.png):

Então acesse Editor de Texto > Sugestões > [Quick Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/islXA.png) e marque como "off" a opção "other".

Comment: resolveu aqui, mt obrigado.

Answer (score -2):

Caso vc queira tirar apenas as descrições de método (como sugestões de métodos e atributos de objetos, nomes de variáveis ​​e funções que ocupam um terço da tela) e deixar as sugestões de nomes de variáveis ​​e funções é só vc procurar nas configs "Editor: Show Parameter Hints" e desabilitar # ;)

Answer (score -3):

Digite (editor.hover.enable) nas configurações e desabilite ou habilite quando quiser.